# Issues while fetching result set in the jboss application

Tags: java, sql-server, jboss

Using the below jboss configuration while fetching the data from resultset it takes more time but using standalone application it's executed quickly.

it takes 20 seconds in jboss and 0.98 seconds in standalone application

I am using database SQL Server 2019

configuration:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/FXDS" pool-name="FXDS" enabled="true" spy="false" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.10:1433;DatabaseName=SQLDB;</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <flush-strategy>Gracefully</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>SA</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <set-tx-query-timeout>true</set-tx-query-timeout>
        <query-timeout>1800</query-timeout>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community. Check the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Hope you will stay with us for a long time :)

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Please describe the problem

Comment: Don't post your `sa` password to the internet.

Comment: Hi @JamesZ it takes 20 seconds in jboss and 0.98 seconds in standalone application

Comment: Is the server on the same host as the SQL server? Have you ruled out a network issue?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan cache on SQL Server to see if the two applications are using the same query options? Some options, such as ARITH_ABORT, are plan-affecting options meaning that they can produce wildly different execution plans when one application sets them ON and another sets them OFF.